# jquery prevent user delete number 1. in edit mode

Tags: jquery

How can I restrict the user from removing 1. in the following input?

```
 <input type="text"value="1.demomomo">
```

Comment: You want to allow him to edit the `demomomo` part, but not the `1` at the beginning?

Comment: You want to make sure that, regardless of the user editing/changing the value, that the `1.` is always the first two characters?

Comment: what's the purpose for this behaviour?

Comment: yes allow to edit the demomomo only but 1. i don't want to delete

Comment: ok. but why? what's the reason of this? how do you use the value of the input?

Comment: because i use number in choice 1-4 when edit if delete number this choice ..demo (1.)ok (2.)no ()yes (4.)all

Answer (score 1):

You can check value at zero index and add if it is not 1

```
$('#txt1').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val()[0] !=1)
    $(this).val(1+$(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Surely `$(this).val(function(i,v){ return v[0] != '1' ? '1' + v : v; });` (though this may be a little confused by it having to be one-line (due to being in a comment). But there's no need to call `.val()` three times.)